# Connect to DB2 with a key pair instead of password?

Tags: unix, db2

Is it possible to authenticate against a remote IBM DB2 LUW 10.1 server with a private/public key pair instead of a password?

Something like:
db2 connect to somedb user conuser1 using /home/conuser1/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: You can only do it by creating your own [authentication plugin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0012013.html?lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ssh keys for this.

You can, however, set up DB2 to use SSL, and authenticate via client SSL certificates.  See the [documentation for configuring SSL.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0025241.html)